# How do I fix an Err 70/freezing with my Canon EOS R-mount camera and Godox flash gear?

Tags: troubleshooting, godox, hotshoe, canon-r-mount

I've got a newer Canon R body that has the new multifunction hotshoe on it, with the edge contacts:

[image: picture of multifunction hotshoe showing edge contacts]

It's supposed to be backwards-compatible with Canon eTTL-II gear that doesn't have the edge contacts. But when I use a Godox flash or transmitter on my new Canon R body, I keep getting "Err 70", or the camera freezes and I have to power cycle it to clear the issue.

[Canon's support website](https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART177668) simply describes an Err 70 on an EOS R body as "A malfunction with the images has been detected." and gives the less-than-helpful advice to turn the camera off, remove then reinsert the battery, and turn it back on again to clear the error. And maybe start a repair.

This is getting annoying, and I can't find a Godox firmware fix for this issue. What's causing the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

### Hotshoe seating is misaligned

Canon made the new multi-function hotshoe a little deeper than the older traditional hotshoe, so a Godox transmitter or speedlight can sit a little too far forward into the hotshoe for good electrical contact. This can affect all the hotshoe electronic communication (TTL, HSS, etc.).

To fix the seating, you have two options:

1. Push the flash/tranmsitter all the way into the hotshoe, then partially lock it down, and slowly pull back until you hear a click as the locking pin engages.
2. Buy an [AD-E1 hotshoe adapter](https://www.usa.canon.com/shop/p/multi-function-shoe-adapter-ad-e1?color=Black&type=New) and use it.

### Speedlight AF-assist miscommunication throws the Err 70

The new hotshoe communication protocol on the R bodies has apparently changed how AF assist functions are communicated and Godox hasn't cracked it yet.

So on the camera body, disable AF assist, set it to use the LED on the camera body. Alternatively, you can also set the AF mode to servo rather than one-shot, which also deactivates AF assist.

See also:  Julian Krakow's youtube video on these issues: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgCcv7sGUdQ